# Mudar cor de fundo do select de modo iterativo Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, select, html-select, background

Olá, galera.

Estou com uma dificuldade de mudar a cor de fundo de vários selects de modo iterativo. Já consigo mudar, mas tenho que especificar o índice manualmente do elemento para isso acontecer. Aqui está um exemplo do que estou fazendo:

```
 <select class="selectpicker bg-success">
            <option class="bg-success" value="caixa">Em caixa</option>
            <option class="bg-warning" value="depositado">Depositado</option>
            <option class="bg-info" value="pago">Pago</option>
            <option class="bg-danger" value="devolvido">Devolvido</option>
 </select>

 <select class="selectpicker bg-success">
            <option class="bg-success" value="caixa">Em caixa</option>
            <option class="bg-warning" value="depositado">Depositado</option>
            <option class="bg-info" value="pago">Pago</option>
            <option class="bg-danger" value="devolvido">Devolvido</option>
 </select>


<script>
    var select = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    // console.log(select[1]);

    var allselect = []
    for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {

        allselect.push(select[i]);

    }

    allselect[0].onchange = function () {

        allselect[0].className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;

    }

    allselect[1].onchange = function () {

        allselect[1].className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar um laço de repetição, por exemplo: `for`, `forEach`, `while` etc.

**Exemplo com `for..of`:**

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (let select of selects) {
    select.addEventListner("change", _ => {
        select.classList.add( this.options[this.selectedIndex].className );
    })
}
```

**Exemplo com `for..in`:**

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (let key in selects) {
    select.addEventListner("change", _ => {
        selects[key].classList.add( this.options[this.selectedIndex].className );
    })
}
```

**Exemplo com `forEach`:**

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

selects.forEach( select => {
    select.addEventListner("change", _ => {
        select.classList.add( this.options[this.selectedIndex].className );
    })
})
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não conhecia o 'for of'. Estava usando o for e não tava dando certo.